# Read Only view in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list

I want to create a read only view in one of my lists. How can I do that?

Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: views are read-only unless you activate tabular editing. Can you precise your requirement?

Comment: I have a list view on which I do some processing. After completion of the processing I want to freeze that is make the view as Read Only. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no out of the box way to do that. You need to write some event hanlder code for this and that triggers the readonly permission change over the list view based on logic that determines the completion of process.

Answer (score 1):

Views are just representations of the data in the List. If you want to freeze the data, you need to then set permissions on the List or individual items. This can be done manually, or you could kick off a workflow to do this. Either way, you can't prevent someone from somehow editing data by changing a View.

Comment: Can you provide some guidance on how can I change the permissions on the list items programmatically. Please guide.

Comment: For web services, you could look at the Permissions methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcpermissions.permissions_methods

Comment: Here is an example using the object model: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/bdb82f15-6d9c-47b3-b511-f8e019347895